# OSGi: How to embed dependencies in a wrapper bundle

Tags: osgi, aem, bnd

We want to use the `google-maps-services` in our AEM project. To be able to use it in the OGSi environment I creates a wrapper bundle that embeds the jar and exports the `com.google.maps` package.
Sadly the bundle cannot be started, because it is missing the following dependencies:

- com.google.appengine.api
- io.opencencus.stats
- io.opencencus.tags
- okhttp3
- okio

I tried to embedd them as well, but for some reason this doesn't seem to work as well.

What am I doing wrong?

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent></parent>
    <artifactId>thirdparty-google-maps-services-bundle</artifactId>
    <name>aem-main - Thirdparty - google-maps-services-bundle</name>
    <description>Wrapper bundle for Google Maps API</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bnd-process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <bnd><![CDATA[
Bundle-Category: thirdparty
Import-Package: javax.annotation;version=0.0.0
Export-Package: com.google.maps.*
Embed-Dependency: google-maps-services,okhttp,okio,opencensus-api,appengine-api-1.0-sdk
-exportcontents: ${packages;VERSIONED}
-snapshot: ${tstamp;yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}
                                ]]></bnd>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                <artifactId>bnd-baseline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissing>false</failOnMissing>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>baseline</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>baseline</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>sling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- D E P E N D E N C I E S                                                -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.maps</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-maps-services</artifactId>
            <version>0.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencensus-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.88</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

After many try and errors, I found what was missing. You need to export the other dependencies as well:
`Export-Package: io.opencensus.tags,io.opencensus.stats,com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch,okhttp3.*,okio.*com.google.maps.*`

And you need to import this for runtime:
`Import-Package: javax.net.*;version=0.0.0`